Proving that graph is class 2
I believe this $4$-regular graph is of class 2, i.e. its edge chromatic number is $4+1 = 5$. However, I am not able to prove it. Somehow I think that the prove should conclude that edge $\{1, 7\}$ needs to be coloured in a fifth colour.
I have been experimenting with the idea that the induced subgraphs on $\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ and $\{8, 9, 10, 11, 12\}$ does not contain any perfect matchings. So a maximal matching should contain edges incident to $7$ and $1$, thus the edge $\{1, 7\}$ is not part of any perfect matching.
Firstly I am very unsure if this is the right approach and second if it is an approach towards my goal, I do not know how to formalize it properly. Any help would be very much appreciated:)


by "maximal" you mean "perfect", right?

yes, sorry for that, edited it now

Without loss of generality colour $(10,9)\to1,(10,8)\to2,(10,12)\to3,(10,11)\to4$, then $(9,11)\to2$. This forces $(11,12)\to1,(8,11)\to3,(8,9)\to4$. Now $(9,12)$ touches edges of all four colours used so far, proving that five colours are necessary.
